# Find a certain word in pipe seperated values

Tags: regex, ruby, logstash

I am trying to figure out how to match a certain word in pipe separated messages.

Ex: 20190614|3|method|user|/test/xyz/1.1|400|0

How do I check every message which starts with "/test" in the 5th value?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you've written so far. We can't write your code for you but we can help you once you've made an attempt.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure about our desired output, we can likely start with an expression similar to:

```
^(.+?)\|(.+?)\|(.+?)\|(.+?)\|\/test\/.+?\|(.+?)\|.+$
```

and check for `test`.

In this [demo](https://regex101.com/r/W5JYlK/1/), the expression is explained, if you might be interested.

#### Example

```
re = /^(.+?)\|(.+?)\|(.+?)\|(.+?)\|\/test\/.+?\|(.+?)\|.+$/m
str = '20190614|3|method|user|/test/xyz/1.1|400|0
20190614|3|method|user|/testt/xyz/1.1|400|0'

str.scan(re) do |match|
    puts match.to_s
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not conveyed clearly, but I'll just assume that a single message is composed of multiple values joined by pipes.

```
n = 5
message = '20190614|3|method|user|/test/xyz/1.1|400|0'
nth_value = message.split('|')[n - 1]
puts 'Matching' if nth_value =~ /^\/test/
```

Convert this to into a function and modify it to suit your needs.

Comment: This is a good answer, but `nth_value.to_s.scan(/^\/test/).any?` is overkill when you could do `nth_value =~ /^\/test/` or `nth_value.start_with?("/test")`.

Comment: @JordanRunning thanks for that. Will edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In Logstash, if you want to filter on messages which starts with "/test" in the 5th value, you can do this (using the regex from Emma):

```
filter {
  if [message] =~ /^(.+?)\|(.+?)\|(.+?)\|(.+?)\|\/test\/.+?\|(.+?)\|.+$/ {
    ...
  }
}
```

Cf https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/event-dependent-configuration.html#conditionals for more information.